# im trying to display an image in my css page but it does not re-size

Tags: css, image

my image does not display as the true size, I've also tried to embed height and width but that does not work either. any idea of the proper code to get my .png to display as the original size?

my code is ----->

```
<div class="divPanel notop nobottom">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div id="divLogo" class="center">
                <a href="index-alt.html" id="divSiteTitle">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Tech Mule" class="img-circle" title="Tech Mule"/>
                </a>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May you upload your image?

Comment: An image will display as it's native size by default, so you have some CSS or JS that is distorting the image. Please give us some code so that we have a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: What is your css code? Do you have '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">' in the head section of your page?

Comment: Thank you for your time in helping me to solve my issue as i am a novice in the web design area.

Comment: Yes I have -----> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: </head>
<body id="pageBody">

<div id="divBoxed" class="container">

    <div class="transparent-bg" style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: -1;zoom: 1;"></div>

    <div class="divPanel notop nobottom">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">

Comment: <div id="divLogo" class="center">
                          <a href="index-alt.html" id="divSiteTitle"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Tech Mule" class="img-circle" title="Tech Mule"/></a></div>
                  </div>

             </div>
            </div>

Comment: this is the code for the frame the image resides in --->

Comment: <div class="divPanel notop nobottom">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">     

                        <div id="divLogo" class="center">
                          <a href="index-alt.html" id="divSiteTitle"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Tech Mule" class="img-circle" title="Tech Mule"/></a></div>
                  </div>

             </div>
            </div>